# Not receiving text messages on phone in trial account

Tags: php, sms, twilio

In my trial account i am using test credentials to send message to a verified twilio account of mine but not receiving that message. Should I use live credentials? Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: Is it possible to receive messages using test credentials or i have to use live credentials in trial account?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't use [test credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials) to send messages or makes calls. Those should only be used to check that your integration is working (i.e. you could use them on your integration tests).

To send real messages you will need to use your live credentials.

Hope this help you

Comment: Now i am using live credentials but again i don't receive messages. I am using auto generated twilio number as From and a verified number as To. The error message is "Permission to send an SMS has not been enabled for the region indicated by the 'To' number: +923470680745."

Comment: That will mean you have not enabled the phone number to send messages to where you're trying to send messages. You can change that by going to Geo Permissions on your account: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international

Comment: I generated a US twilio number by releasing the previous one. This number was able to send global message. Now i am receiving messages. Anyways thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool, make sure you mark the question as answered for future generations ;-)